# What method is fired on sort of store using remoteSort?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I sort of inherited a mess and only have a short time to fix it.  My issue is that I am trying to fix a bug where we are using a store/grid with infinite scrolling. When a user tries to sort the grid a "loading" message appears and that is it.

I have put breakpoints serverside and it is calling back to the server fine and passing the correct columns but it does not ever take the "loading" message off.

I am looking for what event I should watch for on the clientside before and after the sort is fired.  I have console.log statements in load, beforesync and just about everything else on the store (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) perhaps there is something I need to listen for on the grid?

Here is the logs from the prefetch overriding and console.logs...

```
grid store event: ["beforeload", i, Object]
pageSize = 100
grid store event: ["beforeprefetch", i,i]
before prefetch done 
proxy.read done 
end of prefetch 
grid panel event: ["sortchange", i, i, "DESC"]
grid panel event: ["beforestatesave", i, Object]
grid store event: ["totalcountchange", 2] BufferedStore.js:22
grid store event: ["prefetch", i, Array[2], true,i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'sortchange' event should fire on the grid.
The 'beforeload' event should fire before the call to the service is made to get new data.
The 'load' event should fire once the data comes back from the service call.

To debug deeper, after your grid is created and you have a reference to it, say for instance 'rolocGrid', you can then use the Observable utility to monitor all events on the grid and it's store.

This snippet will write to the console for each event to give you insight into what happens in the process:

```
 Ext.util.Observable.capture(rolocGrid.store, function () { console.log('grid store event:', arguments)}, rolocGrid);                                           
 Ext.util.Observable.capture(rolocGrid, function () { console.log('grid event:', arguments)}, rolocGrid);
```

Comment: Sweet thanks I will give this a try tomorrow! I especially appreciate the debugging tips.

Comment: I attached the ouput of prefetch above, do you see anything strange?  it gets all the way through prefetch but then nothing fires after?  What is supposed to come next?  Is there something I can do at the end of prefetch to just say it isn't loading anymore?

Comment: There should be a load event firing from the store. Without that the store still thinks it is waiting for data.  Something about the store config, the view height and the data coming back must not be matching up somehow. Without more access to the config and the response data it is hard to know.

Comment: Thanks John you have been a huge help.  We are in the process of rolling this back now and when we get it working I will post the fix.

Comment: I use this occasionally in my `onLaunch` function to initialize debugging of stores. When doing this, I don't need the reference to a grid, so the second argument to anonymous callback function I just set to `null`. Which also works a charm. For added bonus, I use this log statement: console.log( new Date().getTime()+' store event:', arguments);